# TeamCity on Linux - Is there an easier way to upgrade it?

Tags: ubuntu, teamcity

I installed TeamCity for personal use on Ubuntu Linux, and I'd like to upgrade it. However, the procedure to do it seems a bit messy to me. My undestanding is that I should:
 - Backup everything
 - Delete everything
 - Re-install Teamcity from scratch
 - Reinstall all extra drivers, plugins, etc.

That's way too "manual" and time consuming for my taste, the risk of leaving something behind is too high. Is there a safer way to do the upgrade, which doesn't involve reinstallation?

Thanks in advance for all contributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have **typical installation (Data and custom plugins located in ~/.BuildServer, nothing edited in TeamCity installation files)** you can just:

- Backup server data via WebUI
- Stop server

or this two steps can be replaced with

- Stop server
- Backup server data via maintainDB.sh

Then

- Delete TeamCity installation directory (Data will not be deleted)
- Untar TeamCity-???.tar.gz
- Start server

Complete information about server upgrade can be found in [documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Upgrade).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was very useful. I actually spotted that TeamCity data directory was in "/var/TeamCity/.BuildServer/". I noticed it in time, so I just had to make a copy of it before removing previous installation.

Answer (score 4):

My teamcity server is installed under /opt so adapt to your needs.

- mv /opt/teamcity /opt/teamcity_old
- tar -xvzf TeamCity-xxxxxxxxx.tar.gz
- mv TeamCity /opt/teamcity
- cp -R /opt/teamcity_old/.BuildServer/ /opt/teamcity/.BuildServer/
- cp -R /opt/teamcity_old/conf/ /opt/teamcity/conf (check if you want to copy you changes from configuration files before, especially from server.xml)
- chown -R teamcity. /opt/teamcity
- service teamcity start
- Follow teamcity UI instructions for upgrade